# WCF service not interceptable using Unity 2.0 Interception

Tags: wcf, unity-container, aop

In my WCF web application I have configured the Unity container for Interception. Following is my unity configuration.

```
<unity xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/practices/2010/unity"> 
    <sectionExtension type="Microsoft.Practices.Unity.InterceptionExtension.Configuration.InterceptionConfigurationExtension, Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Interception.Configuration"/>

    <assembly name="Infrastructure" />
    <assembly name="WCFServiceLib1"/>

    <namespace name="Infrastructure"/>
    <namespace name="WCFServiceLib1" />

    <container>
      <extension type="Interception" />
      <register type="IService1" mapTo="Service1">
        <interceptor type="InterfaceInterceptor"/>
        <interceptionBehavior type="LogPerformanceDataBehavior"/>
      </register>
    </container>
</unity>
```

When I try to invoke a method on the service using wcftestclient tool, following exception is thrown.

**ArgumentException - The type WCFServiceLib1.Service1 is not interceptable.**
**Parameter name: interceptedType**

I used the **svctraceviewer** tool to get the above exception details.

Following is the implementation of the class LogPerformanceDataBehavior

```
public class LogPerformanceDataBehavior : IInterceptionBehavior
{
    public IEnumerable<Type> GetRequiredInterfaces()
    {
        return Type.EmptyTypes;
    }

    public IMethodReturn Invoke(IMethodInvocation input, GetNextInterceptionBehaviorDelegate getNext)
    {
        var watch = new Stopwatch();

        watch.Start();
        IMethodReturn methodReturn = getNext()(input, getNext);
        watch.Stop();

        string sb = string.Format("Method {0}.{1} executed in: ({2} ms, {3} ticks){4}",
                                  input.MethodBase.DeclaringType.Name, input.MethodBase.Name,
                                  watch.ElapsedMilliseconds, watch.ElapsedTicks, Environment.NewLine);

        using (StreamWriter outfile = new StreamWriter(@"c:\logs\Performance.txt"))
        {
            outfile.Write(sb);
        }

        return methodReturn;
    }

    public bool WillExecute
    {
        get { return true; }
    }
}
```

What could possibly be wrong?

Comment: Do you try to intercept your _service_ or the _client side proxy_? WCF has its own infrastructure for intercepting calls to services. I don't think this works well with any other interception mechanism (be it Unity or else). If you want to monitor the performance of WCF you should have a look at [WCF performance counters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms735098.aspx)

Comment: @SebastianWeber I am trying to intercept the call to any method on a service. I have used the steps in this [link](http://geekswithblogs.net/13DaysaWeek/archive/2010/12/01/dependency-injection-and-wcf-services.aspx) to configure unity for the service.

Comment: I know about the UnityServiceHost/Factory/InstanceProvider but I'm not sure wether it is a good idea (or even possible) to use Unity's interception mechanism for this scenario.WCF has a pipeline of callhandlers that start with picking calls to the service off the wire, validate them, authorize them, log them and what not.If you are just interested in performance measurements I would stick with WCF built-in perf counters.They are proven,fast and well documented.If you want to use interception for something else:have a look at what the WCF infrastructure gives you.Its built for extensibility.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that the WCF instance provider isn't resolving an interface. Its resolving the service type. You are using an interface interceptor, which cannot be directly applied to a class. See [Comparison of Interception Techniques](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff660861%28v=PandP.20%29.aspx#interception_comparison).

The fix is:

1. Change to a `VirtualMethodInterceptor`.
2. Mark any service methods to be intercepted as `virtual`.

Example registration:

```
<register type="Service1" >         
    <interceptor type="VirtualMethodInterceptor"/> 
    <interceptionBehavior type="LogPerformanceDataBehavior"/>       
</register>
```

Comment: Or you could inherit from MarshalByRefObject and use a TransparentProxyInterceptor or modify the WCF instance provider to resolve by interface.

Comment: If you are just doing an IInstanceProvider then trying to resolve an interface doesn't work. I tried it. WCF wants a class instance and will start throwing exceptions if you give it anything else.


Technically MarshalByRefObject is an option, but that's meant for use with .NET Remoting. Having a WCF service class inherit from .NET remoting seems like a bad idea to me... although admittedly I don't have the expertise to say definitively.